# Customize chrome's omnibox suggestion list

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

Is there any way to modify the omnibox suggestion list - such that:

1. Entries (viz. URLs) can be added
2. The order of an entry be altered

This *may* be achievable by modifying a SQLite file some where.

Note: I am **not** looking for any omnibox-search-keyword based solution.

So far I have not found any link and this will may have to be put forth as a feature request to the chromium team.